# Running macro on multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I can run macro on individual worksheets but not all open worksheets.

I want to run this macro on 700 worksheets. We are trying to delete one column.

```
Sub RunMacroOnAllSheetsToRight()
    For i = ActiveSheet.Index To Sheets.Count
        Call MyFunction(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Function MyFunction(i)
    'Code goes here

    Dim lColumn As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lColumn = 5
    'For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'For iCntr = lColumn To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Cells(1, lColumn)) Then
            Columns(lColumn).Delete
        End If
    'Next ws

    MsgBox "I'm currently on sheet " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
End Function
```

Comment: Are you talking about worksheets on *different* workbooks or worksheets on the *same* workbook?

Comment: On the same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I modified **MyFunction** to make it work:

```
Function MyFunction(i)
    'Code goes here
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(i)
    Dim lColumn As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lColumn = 5
    'For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'For iCntr = lColumn To 1 Step -1
        wks.Activate
        If IsNumeric(wks.Cells(1, lColumn)) Then
            wks.Range(Cells(1, lColumn), Cells(1, lColumn)).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    'Next ws

    MsgBox "I'm currently on sheet " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing
End Function
```

I added the variables `wkb` and `wks` corresponding to the *workbook* and *worksheet*. Using these variables it's easy to refer to the cells of the worksheet and to delete the desired column.

If you need to execute it over 700 worksheets you will need to remove the *MessageBox*. Additionally disabling and enabling `ScreenUpdating` will make it work faster.

Comment: One more question. How we can apply the same logic for rows. For example I want to delete any row that contains text " page".

Comment: You will need to loop row by row. On each row use *find* to know if there is the "text". Something like this: `Set range = wks.Cells.EntireRow.Find("text", , xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlNext, False, , False)` . If *range* is different of **nothing** you delete the `EntireRow`.